# cabal install fails when installing shakespeare-css and derive with Haskell errors

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I am very new to the Haskell platform and I'm having much more trouble than I had wished for with it.

I think I'm getting closer since everything goes well until cabal tries to install `shakespeare-css` and derive.

I'm working on a `Ubuntu 11.10` with `ghc-7.4.2` and cabal-install `1.16.0.2`

When I input command

```
~/.cabal/bin$ ./cabal -v install derive
```

I get the following output

```
Reading available packages...
Choosing modular solver.
Resolving dependencies...
Ready to install derive-2.5.11
Waiting for install task to finish...
Extracting
/home/tamarin/.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org/derive/2.5.11/derive-2.5.11.tar.gz
to /tmp/derive-2.5.11-29920...
Updating derive.cabal with the latest revision from the index.
Configuring derive-2.5.11...
Dependency base ==4.5.1.0: using base-4.5.1.0
Dependency bytestring ==0.9.2.1: using bytestring-0.9.2.1
Dependency containers ==0.4.2.1: using containers-0.4.2.1
Dependency directory ==1.1.0.2: using directory-1.1.0.2
Dependency filepath ==1.3.0.0: using filepath-1.3.0.0
Dependency haskell-src-exts ==1.13.5: using haskell-src-exts-1.13.5
Dependency pretty ==1.1.1.0: using pretty-1.1.1.0
Dependency process ==1.1.0.1: using process-1.1.0.1
Dependency syb ==0.3.7: using syb-0.3.7
Dependency template-haskell ==2.8.0.0: using template-haskell-2.8.0.0
Dependency transformers ==0.2.2.0: using transformers-0.2.2.0
Dependency uniplate ==1.6.10: using uniplate-1.6.10
Using Cabal-1.16.0.3 compiled by ghc-7.0
Using compiler: ghc-7.4.2
Using install prefix: /home/tamarin/.cabal
Binaries installed in: /home/tamarin/.cabal/bin
Libraries installed in: /home/tamarin/.cabal/lib/derive-2.5.11/ghc-7.4.2
Private binaries installed in: /home/tamarin/.cabal/libexec
Data files installed in: /home/tamarin/.cabal/share/derive-2.5.11
Documentation installed in: /home/tamarin/.cabal/share/doc/derive-2.5.11
Using alex version 2.3.5 found on system at: /usr/bin/alex
Using ar found on system at: /usr/bin/ar
No c2hs found
Using cpphs version 1.16 found on system at: /home/tamarin/.cabal/bin/cpphs
No ffihugs found
Using gcc version 4.6.1 found on system at: /usr/bin/gcc
Using ghc version 7.4.2 found on system at: /usr/local/bin/ghc
Using ghc-pkg version 7.4.2 found on system at: /usr/local/bin/ghc-pkg
No greencard found
Using haddock version 2.11.0 found on system at: /usr/local/bin/haddock
Using happy version 1.18.6 found on system at: /usr/bin/happy
No hmake found
Using hpc version 0.6 found on system at: /usr/local/bin/hpc
Using hsc2hs version 0.67 found on system at: /usr/local/bin/hsc2hs
No hscolour found
No hugs found
No jhc found
Using ld found on system at: /usr/bin/ld
No lhc found
No lhc-pkg found
No nhc98 found
Using pkg-config version 0.26 found on system at: /usr/bin/pkg-config
Using ranlib found on system at: /usr/bin/ranlib
Using strip found on system at: /usr/bin/strip
Using tar found on system at: /bin/tar
No uhc found
creating dist/build
creating dist/build/autogen
Building derive-2.5.11...
Preprocessing library derive-2.5.11...
Building library...
creating dist/build
/usr/local/bin/ghc --make -fbuilding-cabal-package -O -odir dist/build -hidir dist/build -stubdir dist/build -i -idist/build -i. -idist/build/autogen -Idist/build/autogen -Idist/build -optP-include -optPdist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -package-name derive-2.5.11 -hide-all-packages -package-conf dist/package.conf.inplace -package-id base-4.5.1.0-8a237511fef48b8f180babb0282b28e3 -package-id bytestring-0.9.2.1-ac1c20630117630ba32abcac9cdbbce8 -package-id containers-0.4.2.1-59c8844d535e4a3bdd1569d60336e3b7 -package-id directory-1.1.0.2-ef4eca075618605e644c6184b111f96f -package-id filepath-1.3.0.0-954c43b4f109cbd4121f1231c14d5cff -package-id haskell-src-exts-1.13.5-3e91c3c2a4a723d046d79dc6b2b3a8bd -package-id pretty-1.1.1.0-867dcdeb02592f3d2a707618561c7b86 -package-id process-1.1.0.1-bd6d91995b2ae2680669549cb63f15b4 -package-id syb-0.3.7-a269c050536d4890f37a20513844e800 -package-id template-haskell-2.8.0.0-785b225a803e6279a067560929c36633 -package-id transformers-0.2.2.0-7f9cf1f6994d36648f58249fe35d1cf2 -package-id uniplate-1.6.10-e06ac94679c647f08eee64b44109aecc -XHaskell98 Data.DeriveMain Data.DeriveTH Data.DeriveDSL Data.Derive.All Data.Derive.DSL.Apply Data.Derive.DSL.Derive Data.Derive.DSL.DSL Data.Derive.DSL.HSE Data.Derive.DSL.SYB Data.Derive.Instance.Arities Data.Derive.Class.Arities Data.Derive.Class.Default Language.Haskell Language.Haskell.Convert Language.Haskell.TH.All Language.Haskell.TH.Compat Language.Haskell.TH.Data Language.Haskell.TH.ExpandSynonym Language.Haskell.TH.FixedPpr Language.Haskell.TH.Helper Language.Haskell.TH.Peephole Data.Derive.Arbitrary Data.Derive.ArbitraryOld Data.Derive.Arities Data.Derive.Binary Data.Derive.BinaryDefer Data.Derive.Bounded Data.Derive.Data Data.Derive.DataAbstract Data.Derive.Default Data.Derive.Enum Data.Derive.EnumCyclic Data.Derive.Eq Data.Derive.Fold Data.Derive.Foldable Data.Derive.From Data.Derive.Functor Data.Derive.Has Data.Derive.Is Data.Derive.JSON Data.Derive.LazySet Data.Derive.Lens Data.Derive.Monoid Data.Derive.NFData Data.Derive.Ord Data.Derive.Read Data.Derive.Ref Data.Derive.Serial Data.Derive.Serialize Data.Derive.Set Data.Derive.Show Data.Derive.Traversable Data.Derive.Typeable Data.Derive.UniplateDirect Data.Derive.UniplateTypeable Data.Derive.Update Data.Derive.Internal.Derivation Data.Derive.Internal.Instance Data.Derive.Internal.Traversal Derive.Main Derive.Derivation Derive.Flags Derive.Generate Derive.Test Derive.Utils
[ 1 of 65] Compiling Language.Haskell.TH.Compat ( Language/Haskell/TH/Compat.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/TH/Compat.o )
[ 2 of 65] Compiling Language.Haskell.TH.Data ( Language/Haskell/TH/Data.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/TH/Data.o )
[ 3 of 65] Compiling Language.Haskell.TH.ExpandSynonym ( Language/Haskell/TH/ExpandSynonym.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/TH/ExpandSynonym.o )
[ 4 of 65] Compiling Language.Haskell.TH.FixedPpr ( Language/Haskell/TH/FixedPpr.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/TH/FixedPpr.o )

Language/Haskell/TH/FixedPpr.hs:404:9:
    Not in scope: data constructor `StarK'
    Perhaps you meant `StarT' (imported from Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax)

Language/Haskell/TH/FixedPpr.hs:405:10:
    Not in scope: data constructor `ArrowK'
    Perhaps you meant `ArrowT' (imported from Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax)
Failed to install derive-2.5.11
World file is already up to date.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
derive-2.5.11 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Which seems to me like a weird compilation error

As for installing shakespeare-css

```
./cabal -v install shakespeare-css
```

I get

```
Reading available packages...
Choosing modular solver.
Resolving dependencies...
Ready to install shakespeare-css-1.0.2
Waiting for install task to finish...
Extracting
/home/tamarin/.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org/shakespeare-css/1.0.2/shakespeare-css-1.0.2.tar.gz
to /tmp/shakespeare-css-1.0.2-2963...
Updating shakespeare-css.cabal with the latest revision from the index.
Configuring shakespeare-css-1.0.2...
Dependency base ==4.5.1.0: using base-4.5.1.0
Dependency parsec ==3.1.3: using parsec-3.1.3
Dependency process ==1.1.0.1: using process-1.1.0.1
Dependency shakespeare ==1.0.3: using shakespeare-1.0.3
Dependency template-haskell ==2.8.0.0: using template-haskell-2.8.0.0
Dependency text ==0.11.2.3: using text-0.11.2.3
Dependency transformers ==0.2.2.0: using transformers-0.2.2.0
Using Cabal-1.16.0.3 compiled by ghc-7.0
Using compiler: ghc-7.4.2
Using install prefix: /home/tamarin/.cabal
Binaries installed in: /home/tamarin/.cabal/bin
Libraries installed in:
/home/tamarin/.cabal/lib/shakespeare-css-1.0.2/ghc-7.4.2
Private binaries installed in: /home/tamarin/.cabal/libexec
Data files installed in: /home/tamarin/.cabal/share/shakespeare-css-1.0.2
Documentation installed in:
/home/tamarin/.cabal/share/doc/shakespeare-css-1.0.2
Using alex version 2.3.5 found on system at: /usr/bin/alex
Using ar found on system at: /usr/bin/ar
No c2hs found
Using cpphs version 1.16 found on system at: /home/tamarin/.cabal/bin/cpphs
No ffihugs found
Using gcc version 4.6.1 found on system at: /usr/bin/gcc
Using ghc version 7.4.2 found on system at: /usr/local/bin/ghc
Using ghc-pkg version 7.4.2 found on system at: /usr/local/bin/ghc-pkg
No greencard found
Using haddock version 2.11.0 found on system at: /usr/local/bin/haddock
Using happy version 1.18.6 found on system at: /usr/bin/happy
No hmake found
Using hpc version 0.6 found on system at: /usr/local/bin/hpc
Using hsc2hs version 0.67 found on system at: /usr/local/bin/hsc2hs
No hscolour found
No hugs found
No jhc found
Using ld found on system at: /usr/bin/ld
No lhc found
No lhc-pkg found
No nhc98 found
Using pkg-config version 0.26 found on system at: /usr/bin/pkg-config
Using ranlib found on system at: /usr/bin/ranlib
Using strip found on system at: /usr/bin/strip
Using tar found on system at: /bin/tar
No uhc found
creating dist/build
creating dist/build/autogen
Building shakespeare-css-1.0.2...
Preprocessing library shakespeare-css-1.0.2...
Building library...
creating dist/build
/usr/local/bin/ghc --make -fbuilding-cabal-package -O -odir dist/build -hidir dist/build -stubdir dist/build -i -idist/build -i. -idist/build/autogen -Idist/build/autogen -Idist/build -optP-DGHC_7_4 -optP-include -optPdist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -package-name shakespeare-css-1.0.2 -hide-all-packages -package-conf dist/package.conf.inplace -package-id base-4.5.1.0-8a237511fef48b8f180babb0282b28e3 -package-id parsec-3.1.3-f18640e50f9a9d34865e30e42bb377e6 -package-id process-1.1.0.1-bd6d91995b2ae2680669549cb63f15b4 -package-id shakespeare-1.0.3-a36c3be30cdeba4668fd1e4115e40bde -package-id template-haskell-2.8.0.0-785b225a803e6279a067560929c36633 -package-id text-0.11.2.3-7427aa3daf930bd36d392386f0ef5048 -package-id transformers-0.2.2.0-7f9cf1f6994d36648f58249fe35d1cf2 -XHaskell98 Text.Cassius Text.Lucius Text.MkSizeType Text.Css Text.IndentToBrace Text.CssCommon -Wall
[1 of 6] Compiling Text.MkSizeType  ( Text/MkSizeType.hs, dist/build/Text/MkSizeType.o )
[2 of 6] Compiling Text.IndentToBrace ( Text/IndentToBrace.hs, dist/build/Text/IndentToBrace.o )
[3 of 6] Compiling Text.Css         ( Text/Css.hs, dist/build/Text/Css.o )
[4 of 6] Compiling Text.CssCommon   ( Text/CssCommon.hs, dist/build/Text/CssCommon.o )
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package bytestring-0.9.2.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package transformers-0.2.2.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package mtl-2.0.1.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package array-0.4.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package deepseq-1.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package text-0.11.2.3 ... linking ... done.
Loading package parsec-3.1.3 ... linking ... done.
Loading package filepath-1.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package old-locale-1.0.0.4 ... linking ... done.
Loading package old-time-1.1.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package unix-2.5.1.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package directory-1.1.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package process-1.1.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package containers-0.4.2.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package pretty-1.1.1.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package template-haskell ... linking ... done.
Loading package shakespeare-1.0.3 ... linking ... done.

Text/CssCommon.hs:159:1:Failed to install shakespeare-css-1.0.2
World file is already up to date.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
shakespeare-css-1.0.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 11
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: The first problem seems to be caused by the fact that you're using `template-haskell-2.8.0.0` where `ghc-7.4.2` ships with `template-haskell-2.7.0.0`. Could you try if passing the additional flag `--constraint="template-haskell == 2.7.0.0"` helps?

Comment: I tried. Before the installs it threatens me, telling me that aeson shakespeare are going to be broken since they expect to be built with template-haskell-2.8.0.0 and after the process I end up with more error messages.
Any other suggestion ?

Comment: I don't understand. `derive` doesn't depend on `aeson`. And no reinstallation should be necessary, as you should already have `template-haskell-2.7.0.0` installed.

Comment: Sorry I tried with shakespeare-css, not derive. With derive I get the following error (I put it on pastebin)
http://pastebin.com/eq7sdQGZ

Comment: That's not enough context. Is it trying to reinstall `template-haskell-2.7.0.0`? What does `ghc-pkg list template-haskell` say?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but I did a fresh install of an Ubuntu 12.10 and everything worked right off the box so I think I'm going to give up on finding the answer for that one :)

Comment: @AlexandreYamajako: Can you close this question since you don't intend to ever get it answered?